# Where can I ask about companies analyzing meal powders?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/44488/what-types-of-a-company-can-verify-the-contents-of-the-meal-replacement-powder) question on the Physical Fitness site because I thought it was one of the very few StackExchange sites where it can be asked. Turns out it's off-topic there.

On which site can I ask this question?
Or can this question be reworded to be acceptable for the Physical Fitness site?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, unfortunately it falls outside the scope for the Fitness site. I think the best fit might be the [cooking site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), but I haven't read their on-topic page recently, so I wasn't confident that I should just move it outright.

Each site has its own Help Center, with an [on-topic](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page that gives a glimpse into what kind of questions are on and off topic, so definitely read theirs before you ask over there.

That said, if you find that theirs also prohibits the type of question you want to ask, then it might just be one of those questions that doesn't fit any of the Stack Exchange sites. Remember that there's no guarantee that a question fits on any of them.

Comment: I did ask Seasoned Advice and it's borderline. If it were deemed on-topic, however, OP likely won't get an answer so not worth the migration.